# Svelte build is inside a folder named public

Tags: svelte

In the default project of svelte, when you run start, the `build` folder contain all built js and css files.

In my project, the result is the following.

[image]

I checked my config, and it's pretty much like the original one (expected the fact that I added tailwing :

package.json

```
    "watch:tailwind": "postcss public/tailwind.css -o public/index.css -w",
    "build:tailwind": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production postcss public/tailwind.css -o public/index.css",    
    "build": "npm run build:tailwind && rollup -c",
    "start": "sirv public",
    "serve": "serve public -p 80",
    "dev": "concurrently \"rollup -c -w\" \"npm run watch:tailwind\"",
```

rollup.config

```
import svelte from "rollup-plugin-svelte";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import livereload from "rollup-plugin-livereload";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import sveltePreprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
  let server;

  function toExit() {
    if (server) server.kill(0);
  }

  return {
    writeBundle() {
      if (server) return;
      server = require("child_process").spawn(
        "npm",
        ["run", "start", "--", "--dev"],
        {
          stdio: ["ignore", "inherit", "inherit"],
          shell: true,
        }
      );

      process.on("SIGTERM", toExit);
      process.on("exit", toExit);
    },
  };
}

export default {
  input: "src/main.ts",
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: "iife",
    name: "app",
    file: "public/build/bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      // enable run-time checks when not in production
      dev: !production,
      // we'll extract any component CSS out into
      // a separate file - better for performance
      css: (css) => {
        css.write("public/build/bundle.css");
      },
      preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
    }),

    // If you have external dependencies installed from
    // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
    // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
    // consult the documentation for details:
    // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ["svelte"],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ sourceMap: !production }),

    // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
    // the bundle has been generated
    !production && serve(),

    // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
    // browser on changes when not in production
    !production && livereload("public"),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    production && terser(),
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false,
  },
};
```

Do someone as an idea of why ?

and

Answer (score 4):

The location of the `.js` files is as expected.
However to write the `.css` files your config has the following:

```js
css.write("public/build/bundle.css");
```

The path given to `css.write` however is relative to the location of the js file, giving you the issue you have:

```
.JS: public/build/ bundle.js
CSS: public/build/ public/build/bundle.css
```